# I had "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." error while writing a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Guys I am trying to write such a function. When the value of the data frame's column is less than 30, it should be equal to 1 otherwise, it should be equal to 0 but when I try to apply this function to my own data
it didn't work

```
def age_flag(dataframe,column):
    if pd.DataFrame({column:dataframe[column]}) < 30:
        return dataframe[column] == 1
    else:
        return dataframe[column] == 0
```

Comment: `dataframe[column]` is, as the name implies, a _column_, containing many values. Some of those values may equal 1, some may equal 0, and some may be neither. `dataframe[column] == 1` is a meaningless comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```py
import pandas as pd


def age_flag(df: pd.DataFrame, column_name: str):
    return (df[column_name] < 30).astype(int).to_numpy()
```

Although I'm unclear what output type you want. The above returns a numpy array of `int`s. If you want a dataframe, just remove the `.values` at the end. And if you want a `list` add a `.tolist()` after `.values`.

Comment: Note that `values` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) in favor of `to_numpy()`.